# wordpress custom theme - getelementbyid to access element in header.php returning null

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress-theming

I am new to Wordpress dev. I'm trying to add a burger menu dropdown, but trying to call the icon to click by getElementbyID is returning null for some reason. Other code in the js file is registering, so I beleive I have it encoded correctly. I am unsure if there is some aspect of the DOM tree or encoding for wordpress themes that I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

in header.php

```
<div id="nav_icon_burger_x"> 
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
```

in app.js

```
const mobileNavIcon = document.getElementById('nav_icon_burger_x');

mobileNavIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
    mobileNavIcon.toggleClass('open');
});
```

in functions.php

```
function include_js_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script('idm250-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/app.js');
}

// When WP performs this action, call our function
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js_files');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that have saved me in the first place is to add a simple onclick property to menu button. Like this:

```
<div onclick="toggleFunction(event)"> 
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Then you put your function anywhere:

```
function toggleFunction(e){          
  e.target.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

There is also a problem on your code, toggleClass is from jQuery, so you need a Jquery element to toggle its classes, on vanilla you can use, classList.toggle('yourClass')

If you need to use jQuery for this, use your function like this:

```
$('#nav_icon_burger_x').toggleClass('open')
```

Inside your addEventListener function

You can go further and make the click event from jQuery Like this:

```
$('#nav_icon_burger_x').click( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```js
function toggleFunction(e){          
  e.target.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  width:30px;
  height:36px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
span{
  background-color:black;
  height:10px;
  width:30px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  
}
.open{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleFunction(event)"> 
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you achieve your goal.

Comment: thank you, I got it working using code like this. It was a CSS error as it turns out. Your help is greatly appreciated